# Looking for a story about a princess trapped inside a gemstone

Tags: story-identification

I remember from my childhood the following story that my grandmother told me.
It was about a young man who discovers a gemstone in a jeweller's shop or a market. I believe the gemstone, exerted a mystery attraction on him. I'm not sure why, maybe because the stone was too expensive, but he stole it and was caught and sentenced to death for it, but he was saved by an old man before the execution. The old man revealed to the young man that the precious stone was the prison of a princess enchanted by an evil sorcerer.  Before vanishing, the old man told how the princess could be temporarily released from her spell.

The young man followed the old man's directions and managed to wake up the princess. When asked if he could free her from her prison, she said that she was not allowed to reveal anything and it solidified again in the stone. Some time later, the young guy runs across the old man again, who exposes himself to be a King or so who has been searching for his missing daughter for a long time. He asked the young man to sell him the stone, but the latter is in love with the princess and refusing to sell the stone threw it into a river or pond avoiding it falling into the old man's hands or others. Immediately after, the princess reappears: the young man unconsciously broke the curse by willingly giving up the stone rather than selfishly keeping it to himself, as all prior owners had done. Then, the king gratefully offered the young man his daughter as a marriage and appointed him the heir to his empire.

I believe the chronological order of the story is pretty much as I just related it. I can't remember whether the gemstone was a diamond or a ruby (or other precious stone). My grandmother also told my siblings and me that if you genuinely want something, you should let it go and believe that if it is yours, it will come back to you.